# An array of nested forms, but I do not want the previous completed objects to show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms

I have an Object where the object has a nested form of which can be duplicated as needed.

To accomplish this I am using :

```
- 2.times { @organization.referrals.build }
- form_for @organization do |f|
  = f.error_messages
  - f.fields_for :referrals do |qf|
    = render :partial => 'referral_fields', :locals => {:qf => qf}
```

Now I have two blank `referrals` for them to fill out. But I do not want the user to see the older created `referrals`. How do I keep the nested model form, but dissalow the end user from seeing the previously created objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work...

```
f.fields_for @organization.referrals.select{|r| r.new_record?} do |qf|
```

Comment: This knocks out my 2.times method. I wonder if there's something that still allows me to have multiple extra duplicates of an empty form.